# Divs are not displaying one by one in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know `div` elements are block level elements. They come one by one in different rows. I found one strange behavior. It is not displaying one by one.

```
<div id ="contend">
   <div style='position:relative'> <div class='serach-box'>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Live Search</p>

            <!--Row with two equal columns-->
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-md-3" >
                    <div class="demo-content">Location</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" >
                    <div class="demo-content bg-alt">.col-sm-6</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Row with two equal columns-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>

</div>
```

I added two `div` elements after completing the `serach-box` `div`. I gave `serach-box` a `position: absolute;` and its parent `div` `position: relative;`.

But why did `div` text appear above ? Why not below the `serach-box` `div`?

Code is below:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ONrHDKuaP9bwmT7MsQhD?p=preview

```
.serach-box{
    width: 90%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position:absolute;
    left:5%;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the search box is absolutely positioned, it is taken out of normal flow.

Since it isn't in normal flow, it has no influence over the height of its container.

Since its container has no other content, the container ends up with a height of zero.

The elements following the container are, therefore, not pushed down by the container's height.

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning. There doesn't seem to be any point in using it in your example in the first place.

Comment: ok ..I got your point ..so if you gave one situation to make search bar as I did ..which is center to horizontal and some margin from top how you can do without position absolute

Comment: please check http://plnkr.co/edit/ONrHDKuaP9bwmT7MsQhD?p=preview if  remove margin I am not able to give margin .

Comment: Not really. I don't really know what you code is trying to achieve. If you have a problem with vertical margins, then it is problem down to [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

Answer (score -1):

your position absolute will cause the text to find its way to the top.
Absolute means it will 'hover' on top of the page.

you can set the position to relative and add some with and height to place the box at the top.

just replace absolute for relative

Answer (score -1):

To the div which is relatively positioned, its taking no height so, both the div's with 'hello' text are displaying there itself.

Give some min-height to the relatively positioned div.

<div style='position:relative;min-height: 32%'>

....
....

</div>

Which will work fine for you.